# Using dict_cursor in django

Tags: python, django

To get a cursor in django I do:

```
from django.db import connection
cursor = connection.cursor()
```

How would I get a dict cursor in django, the equivalent of -

```
import MySQLdb
connection = (establish connection)
dict_cursor = connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
```

Is there a way to do this in django? When I tried `cursor = connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)` I got a `Exception Value: cursor() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)`. Or do I need to connect directly with the python-mysql driver?

The django docs suggest using `dictfetchall`:

```
def dictfetchall(cursor):
    "Returns all rows from a cursor as a dict"
    desc = cursor.description
    return [
        dict(zip([col[0] for col in desc], row))
        for row in cursor.fetchall()
    ]
```

Is there a performance difference between using this and creating a dict_cursor?

Answer (score 51):

No there is no such support for `DictCursor` in Django. 
But you can write a small function to that for you. 
See docs: [Executing custom SQL directly](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly):

```
def dictfetchall(cursor): 
    "Returns all rows from a cursor as a dict" 
    desc = cursor.description 
    return [
            dict(zip([col[0] for col in desc], row)) 
            for row in cursor.fetchall() 
    ]

>>> cursor.execute("SELECT id, parent_id from test LIMIT 2");
>>> dictfetchall(cursor)
[{'parent_id': None, 'id': 54360982L}, {'parent_id': None, 'id': 54360880L}]
```

Comment: I guess this answer helps a lot of people who come here. But if you read the original question, then the answer does not match: Is there a performance difference between using dictfetchall() and creating a dict_cursor?

Answer (score 11):

Easily done with Postgres at least, i'm sure mysql has similar ( Django 1.11)

```
from django.db import connections
from psycopg2.extras import NamedTupleCursor


def scan_tables(app):
    conn = connections['default']
    conn.ensure_connection()
    with conn.connection.cursor(cursor_factory=NamedTupleCursor) as cursor:
        cursor.execute("SELECT table_name, column_name "
                       "FROM information_schema.columns AS c "
                       "WHERE table_name LIKE '{}_%'".format(app))
        columns = cursor.fetchall()
        for column in columns:
            print(column.table_name, column.column_name)


scan_tables('django')
```

Obviously feel free to use DictCursor, RealDictCursor, LoggingCursor etc

Comment: It doesn't work with Django cursor. To use this feature you should import psycopg2 cursor. Tested with Django==1.11.6

Comment: The second line in my code snippet explicitly says `from psycopg2.extras import NamedTupleCursor`

Comment: Gives me TypeError: cursor() got an unexpected keyword argument 'cursor_factory'
in Django 2.x .

Comment: This worked for me.  Note that kert is using `connections["default"].connection.cursor()` and not `connections["default"].cursor()`.

Comment: @DanielQuinn points out the precise important detail, the extra `.connection`! Easy to overlook!

Answer (score 5):

The following code converts the result set into a dictionary.

```
from django.db import connections
cursor = connections['default'].cursor()

columns = (x.name for x in cursor.description)
result = cursor.fetchone()
result = dict(zip(columns, result))
```

If the result set has multiple rows, iterate over the cursor instead.

```
columns = [x.name for x in cursor.description]
for row in cursor:
    row = dict(zip(columns, row))
```

Comment: Just an interesting side note. Expression (x.name for x in cursor.description) produces a generator not a list object. Such generator will be exhausted after the first iteration of the "for row in cursor" loop. To make this code sample work on multiple rows we need to pre-fetch columns by changing round brackets to square brackets: [x.name for x in cursor.description]

Answer (score 4):

The main Purpose of using RealDictCursor is to get data in list of dictionary format.

And the apt solution is this and that too without using django ORM

def fun(request):

```
from django.db import connections

import json

from psycopg2.extras import  RealDictCursor



con = connections['default']
con.ensure_connection()
cursor= con.connection.cursor(cursor_factory=RealDictCursor)
cursor.execute("select * from Customer")
columns=cursor.fetchall()
columns=json.dumps(columns)
```

output:

[{...},{...},{......}]