# create nested json from the ouput of two queries django

Tags: python, json, django

My code snippet looks like this:

## views.py

```
def get_milestonebased_deals(request):

           cursor = connection.cursor()
           cursor.execute("SELECT id,deal_title, milestone_order_id  from myapp_milestone")
           row = cursor.fetchall()
           cursor2=connection.cursor()
           cursor2.execute("select id, title, deal_milestone_id created from myapp_deals")
           row2=cursor2.fetchall()
           data_dict = ValuesQuerySetToDict(row)
           data_json = json.dumps(data_dict)
           data_dict2 = ValuesQuerySetToDict(row2)
           data_jsonn = json.dumps([data_dict2])
           return json_response({
                               'status':data_json,
                               
                          })
```

I want to create json object as below from the above function:

```
[{
"id":"1",
"title":"Lead",
"milestone":[{
    "id":"1",
    "deal_title":"Staff",
    "created":"date"
    },
    {
    "id":"2",
    "deal_title":"Staff2",
    "created":"date"
    },
    {"id":"1",
    "deal_title":"Staff3",
    "created":"date"
    }]
},
{"id":"2",
"title":"Lead2",
"milestone":[{
    "id":"1",
    "deal_title":"employee",
    "created":"date"
    },
    {
    "id":"2",
    "deal_title":"employee3",
    "created":"date"
    }]
}]
```

Can anyone suggest does it possible, if so then how?

Comment: How about `'status': [data_json, data_jsonn]`?

Comment: nope..@ Leistungsabfall . the instances whose deal_milestone from deals table = milestone_order_id from the milestone table should come under milestone. For example, if 4 instances from the deals table have milestone_order_id =1 in milestone table then that are should come under the instance which has milestone_order_id =1. Its similar to array_merge_recursive in php.

Comment: Can you share your models ??

Comment: #Deals model:                                                                                               class Deals(models.Model):
    contact_id = models.IntegerField()
    deal_title=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    deal_value = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    currency_id = models.IntegerField()
    deal_milestone=models.IntegerField()

#Milestone model         class Milestone(models.Model):
    user = models.IntegerField()
    process= models.IntegerField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    milestone_order_id=models.IntegerField()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think of 2 solutions for this question:

1. [Using django-rest-framework nested serializers](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/)
2. The following provided sample:

First you should read `myapp_deals` and `iterate` among the records and add correspond `milestone` to each record and the dumps the whole list

I've provide a sample with `sqlite` and my tables called `header` and `detail` as simplicity.

> It's written in simple python but you can use code in your django view

```
import sqlite3
import json

def dict_factory(cursor, row):
    '''
    Provides DictCursor for sqlite
    '''
    d = {}
    for idx, col in enumerate(cursor.description):
        d[col[0]] = row[idx]
    return d

conn = sqlite3.connect('db.sqlite')
conn.row_factory = dict_factory
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('''SELECT * FROM HEADER''')
headers_list = list(cur.fetchall())
for header in headers_list:    
    cur.execute('SELECT * FROM DETAIL WHERE HEADER_ID=' + str(header['id']))
    row = cur.fetchone()
    if row is not None:
       header['details'] = row
cur.close()

print(json.dumps(headers_list))
```

result:

```
[{"id": 1, "details": {"header_id": 1, "id": 1, "des": "des1"}, "name": "name1"}
, {"id": 2, "details": {"header_id": 2, "id": 3, "des": "des3"}, "name": "name2"
}]
```

Comment: i got 'tuple' object does not support item assignment error for the following line header['details'] = row

Comment: Sure, as my sample I first converted tuple to list `headers_list = list(cur.fetchall())` and also converted each record to dictionary

Comment: Tuples (each record) should be converted to dict, there is a built-in solution for mysql and I've provided for Sqlite, What DB are u using?

Comment: I am using mysqldb and i have used the following built in solution:
def dictfetchall(cursor,row):

    desc = cursor.description
    return [
            dict(zip([col[0] for col in desc], row))
            for row in cursor.fetchall()
    ]

Comment: i have followed this  link for mysql dict cursor: "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888844/using-dict-cursor-in-django ". @Serjik

Comment: Thanks @Serjik. I have found the issue.. Thank you so much for yor response

Comment: I'm glad that it was helpful

Comment: I am getting Attribute error, while following these steps:
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `email` on serializer `userSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `str` instance.

Have created a question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66734815/serializing-list-of-object-in-django-to-nested-json

Can someone help me on this