# Serializing list of object in Django to nested json

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am new to Django/Python and was trying to work on project.
I have to create an API with nested values like below

```
{
"rule": "ruleA"
 "criticality" : "High"
 "user": [
           {
            "email" : "xyz@gmail.com"
            "username" : "xyz"
            },
            {
            "email" : "abc@gmail.com"
            "username" : "abc"
            }
          ]
}
{
"rule": "ruleB"
 "criticality" : "low"
 "user": [
           {
            "email" : "pqr@gmail.com"
            "username" : "pqr"
            }
          ]
}
```

Below is my serializer.py

```
class userSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    email = serializers.CharField()
    username= serializers.CharField()


class cloudScoreAnalysisSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    rules = serializers.CharField()
    criticality = serializers.CharField()
    user = userSerializer(many=True,source='*')
```

**views.py**

```
class scoreAnalysisView(views.APIView):

    def queryset_scoreAnalysisView(self,user):
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor_1 = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute("Parent data MY SQL Query", (user,))
        data_list = list(self.dictfetchall(cursor))
        for data in data_list:
            #print(data)
            cursor_1.execute("Child data MY SQL Query)", (user,))
            rows_list = list(self.dictfetchall(cursor_1))
            r =[]
            keys = ('email','username')
            for rw in rows_list:
                r.append(zip(keys,rw))
            data['details'] = rows_list
        result = []
        keys = ('rules', 'criticality', 'user')
        for row in data_list:
            result.append(dict(zip(keys,row)))
            json_data = json.dumps(data_list)
            print(json_data)
        return result

    def get(self, request):
        result = self.queryset_scoreAnalysisView(request.user)
        serializer = cloudScoreAnalysisSerializer(result, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

    def dictfetchall(self,cursor):
        "Returns all rows from a cursor as a dict"
        desc = cursor.description
        return [
                dict(zip([col[0] for col in desc], row))
                for row in cursor.fetchall()
        ]
```

While running this code I'm getting attribute error:

```
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `email` on serializer `userSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `str` instance.
```

It seems like the code is unable to find the email filed as it's inside the json array ([ { } ]) .
Kindly help.

Edit:
Added my views.py , if I am doing something wrong there.

Comment: What do your models look like? Are you using the correct relation (related name) on the `cloudScoreAnalysisSerializer`? The error basically means that when serializing the cloudScore object  it is trying to apply the `userSerializer` to an `str`. The usage of `source='*'` has me curious about it as well - you'd be passing the  entire `cloudScore` object into the `userSerializer` (https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source)

Comment: Just remove the `source='*'` and it should work. Also, please, properly CamelCase name your serializer classes

Comment: @henriquesalvaro I don't have models for this API, as I am joining 3-4 tables/models to get the required columns from DB. I haven't used django ORM instead used the raw sql. So that's why I haven't used ModelSerializer as well.

Comment: @gmc Still I'm getting same error !!

Comment: so your problem here is that with the queries you're using, you're probably returning just a  `str` for your `user`? it's hard to gauge without understanding what exactly is the returning format - check that and then you can probably act accordingly (if it's a json string, you can use a `json.loads`, etc)