# How to get key(column name)-value pair from a Select query using default connection in Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql, cursor, psycopg2

I have 4 applications in one Django Project. I am using the default Postgres database connection which I have included it in my `setting.py` file.

The object `django.db.connection` represents the default database connection. To use the database connection, I call `connection.cursor()` to get a cursor object. Then, I call `cursor.execute(sql, [params])` to execute the raw Postgres queries and `cursor.fetchone()` or `cursor.fetchall()` to return the resulting rows.

Now, in one application I want to use the (`connection.cursor(cursor_factory = psycopg2.extras.RealDictCursor)`) to get the records in a `(key(column name), value)` pair, which is provided by `psycopg2.connect` but the default connection that I have is not compatible with `cursor_factory = psycopg2.extras.RealDictCursor`.

How do I get a `(key(column name), value)` pair from the database by using the default connection?
In setting.py

```
`DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',      
        'OPTIONS' : {
                'options': '-c search_path=django,public'
            },
        'NAME': 'postgres',
        'USER': 'abc',
        'PASSWORD': 'password!',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
`
```

In python file .py

```
from django.db import connection

cur = connection.cursor(cursor_factory = psycopg2.extras.RealDictCursor) 
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM sometable") 

data= cur.fetchall()
```

> `ERROR: cursor() got an unexpected keyword argument 'cursor_factory'`

Comment: Have you tried `cursor_factory = psycopg2.extras.DictCursor`? Just reading the relevant docs - http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html

Comment: @user2480526 I tried the below, it still didnt work, `cursor_factory = psycopg2.extras.DictCursor cur= connection.cursor(cursor_factory) Error :cursor() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given `

Answer (score 1):

You have to get an underlying postgres connection, ensure it is established and then you can specify custom cursor_factory.

```
from django.db import connections
import psycopg2


def scan_tables(app):
    conn = connections['default']
    conn.ensure_connection()
    with conn.connection.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.RealDictCursor) as cursor:
        cursor.execute("SELECT table_name, column_name "
                       "FROM information_schema.columns AS c "
                       "WHERE table_name LIKE '{}_%'".format(app))
        print(cursor.fetchall())


scan_tables('django')
```

This is an adapted answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/48844401/803174 @kert just putting different cursor type.