# How to create a table from fetchall dictionary variable? Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a dictionary being created from the result of a query using cursor.
I have defined "dictfetchall(cursor):" in order to convert the result into a dictionary as shown below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIW8b.png)

[This is the code where the variable is created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/74WfX.png)

[This is my index.html table code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTj1g.png)

The data gets called correctly but the table never appears

Comment: try it `for key in data`.

Comment: Please paste code instead of images of code, see how do I ask a good question [ask].

Answer (score 0):

The `context` already is a dictionary, so you should iterate through its key which is `data` that contains dict, so:

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        {% for key in data.keys %}
            {{key}}
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
    <tr>
        {% for value in data.values %}

            <td>
                {% for v in value %}
                    {{v}}
                {% endfor %}

            </td>

        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I tried this, but it returns nothing. It appears to be an issue with the .keys method ? Also tried .items Any idea what could be causing this. 
Thank you !

Comment: @vickyA It's not very clear in the images, make separate question with details and paste code instead of images, also recommend you to go through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10888844) question.